# Scraping a forum page with Beautiful Soup 4 -- csv file ends up empty

Tags: html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I'm trying to scrape a bunch of HTML files for a research project, and it's not working. The csv file ends up empty, except the four column names, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've done a similar scraping job once before, but this website's html seems messier (or perhaps the other was unusually clean).

I hope someone out there can help, and please forgive the code I've written -- I don't have much experience.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib2
import os

def processData( pageFile ): 
    f = open(pageFile, "r")
    page = f.read()
    f.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    one = soup.findAll("td", attrs={"class":"t_user"})
    two = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class":"right t_number"})
    three = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"style":"font-size: 9pt"})
    four = soup.findAll("div", atrs={"style":"padding-top: 4px;"})

    names = []
    threads = []
    posts = []
    timestamps = []

    for html in one:
        names.append(BeautifulSoup(str(name)).get_text().encode("utf-8").strip())

    for html in two:
        threads = BeautifulSoup(str(thread).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("\n", "")

    for html in three:
        posts = BeautifulSoup(str(post).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("\n", "")

    for html in four:
        text = BeautifulSoup(str(html).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("\n", "")
        timestamps.append(text.split("Post at:")[1].strip())

    csvfile = open('S141test.csv', 'ab')    
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    for name, thread, post, timestamp in zip(names, threads, posts, timestamps):
            writer.writerow([name, thread, post, timestamp])

    csvfile.close()

dir = "S141test"
csvfile = "S141test.csv"
csvfile = open(csvfile, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
writer.writerow(["Name", "thread", "post", "timestamp"])
csvfile.close()
# get a list of files in the directory
fileList = os.listdir(dir)
# define variables we need for status text
totalLen = len(fileList)
count = 1
# iterate through files and read all of them into the csv file
for htmlFile in fileList:
    path = os.path.join(dir, htmlFile) # get the file path
    processData(path) # process the data in the file
    print "Processed '" + path + "'(" + str(count) + "/" + str(totalLen) + ")..." # display status
    count = count + 1 # incriment counter
```

The html I'm trying to scrape: (the stuff I want to scrape is highlighted in capital letters, look for AUTHOR NAME, THREAD TITLE, TIMESTAMP, POST CONTENT).

```
HTML S141
<div class="maintable">
<div class="spaceborder" style="width: 100%; border-bottom: none">
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" width="100%" align="center">
<tr class="header"><td colspan="2" style="color: #000000">
<div class="right" style="font-weight: normal">
<a href="misc.php?action=emailfriend&amp;tid=50510">Email to Friend</a> |
<a href="my.php?item=subscriptions&amp;subadd=50510">Subscription</a> |
<a href="my.php?item=favorites&amp;favadd=50510&amp;type=thread">Favorites</a>
</div>
Subject:
Ayuki - TST HG</td></tr>
</table></div>
<form method="post" name="delpost" action="topicadmin.php?action=delpost&amp;fid=28&amp;tid=50510&amp;page=1">
<input type="hidden" name="formhash" value="66b6dc45">
<div class="spaceborder" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 4px;
 border-top: none
">
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" width="100%" align="center" class="t_row">
<tr style="height: 100%">
<td width="18%" valign="top" class="t_user"> <a name="lastpost"></a><a href="viewpro.php?uid=7455" target="_blank" class="bold">asta (AUTHOR NAME)</a>
<br><div class="smalltxt">
Carnal Conqueror<br>
<img src="images/website141.COM/star_level2.gif" alt="Rank: 3" /><img src="images/website141.COM/star_level1.gif" alt="Rank: 3" /><br>
<br>
<br><br>
UID 7455<br>
Digest Posts
0<br>
Credits 328<br>
Posts 28<br>
Karma 327 <br>
Money 156 <br>
Acceptance 25 <br>
Reading Access 30<br>
Registered 20-1-2008<br>
Status Offline
</div>
</td>
<td width="82%" valign="top" style="padding: 0px">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" class="t_msg">
<tr><td>
<div>
<div class="right t_number"><a href="###" class="bold" onclick="window.clipboardData.setData('text','http://forum.website141.com/eforum/viewthread.php?tid=50510&amp;page=1#pid502926')">#1</a></div>
<div style="padding-top: 4px;">
Post at 26-6-2014 00:20 (TIMESTAMP)&nbsp;
<a href="viewpro.php?uid=7455">Profile</a>
<a href="pm.php?action=send&amp;uid=7455" target="_blank">P.M.</a>&nbsp;
</div></div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top" class="line" height="100%" style="padding-top: 10px;">
<a name="pid502926" href="misc.php?action=viewratings&amp;tid=50510&amp;pid=502926" title="[Rating] 29"><img src="images/website141.COM/agree.gif" border="0" align="right" alt="" /><img src="images/website141.COM/agree.gif" border="0" align="right" alt="" /><img src="images/website141.COM/agree.gif" border="0" align="right" alt="" /></a>
<div class="right t_number">Font size:
<a style="cursor:hand" onclick="text502926.style.fontSize='9pt';">S</a>
<a style="cursor:hand" onclick="text502926.style.fontSize='12pt';">M</a>
<a style="cursor:hand" onclick="text502926.style.fontSize='15pt';">L</a></div>
<span class="bold" style="color: #999999">Ayuki - TST HG (THREAD TITLE) </span><br><br>
<div style="font-size: 9pt" id=text502926><a href="http://go141.com/en/27120-Tsim%20Sha%20Tsui%20-%20Honey%20Girls%20-%20Ayuki.html" target="_blank">http://go141.com/en/27120-Tsim%2 ... ls%20-%20Ayuki.html</a><br />
<br />
Do I recommend her ? It depends what you are looking for.
<br />
I asked to take a photo but she didn't allow. (POST CONTENT) </div>
<br><fieldset><legend><a href="misc.php?action=viewratings&amp;tid=50510&amp;pid=502926" title="View Rating Log">Recent Ratings</a></legend><br>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td><a href="viewpro.php?uid=71695" target="_blank">banter141a</a></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;2-7-2014 13:31</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Karma</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>+3</b></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="viewpro.php?uid=97825" target="_blank">hlau</a></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;28-6-2014 00:36</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Karma</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>+6</b></td>
```

Comment: Anyone out there who might be able to help?

Comment: Add more `print`'s to see what's going on in the script.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. It took me several hours, but I eventually figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. I'm not sure whether to delete the question or answer it with my own solution, but I'm going for the latter in case someone else has a very similar problem. One key mistake was that I confused csvfile with csvFile (I needed to use both in distinct ways, as seen in the code below).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib2
import os

def processData( pageFile ): 
    f = open(pageFile, "r")
    page = f.read()
    f.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    one = soup.findAll('td', attrs={"width": "18%"}) #close
    two = soup.findAll("span", attrs={"style":"color: #999999"})  #close
    three = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"style":"font-size: 9pt"}) #works
    four = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"style":"padding-top: 4px;"}) 


    names = []
    threads = []
    posts = []
    timestamps = []

    print four

    for html in one:
            text = BeautifulSoup(str(html).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("\n", " ")
            names.append(text.split('UID')[0].strip()) #works, at the moment

    for color in two:
            text2 = BeautifulSoup(str(color).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("\n", "")
            threads.append(text2.strip())

    for html in three:
            text3 = BeautifulSoup(str(html).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
            posts.append(text3.strip())

    for html in four:
            text4 = BeautifulSoup(str(html).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
            timestamps.append(text4.split("Post at")[1].split('Profile')[0].strip())

    csvfile = open('S141test.csv', 'ab')    
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    for name, thread, post, timestamp in zip(names, threads, posts, timestamps):
            writer.writerow([name, thread, post, timestamp])

    csvfile.close()


dir = "S141test"
csvFile = "S141test.csv"
csvfile = open(csvFile, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
writer.writerow(["Name", "thread", "post", "timestamp"])
csvfile.close()

# get a list of files in the directory
fileList = os.listdir(dir)
# define variables we need for status text
totalLen = len(fileList)
count = 1
# iterate through files and read all of them into the csv file
for htmlFile in fileList:
    path = os.path.join(dir, htmlFile) # get the file path
    processData(path) # process the data in the file
    print "Processed '" + path + "'(" + str(count) + "/" + str(totalLen) + ")..." # display status
    count = count + 1 # incriment counter
```